# How to add interval hours to a timestamp in postgres, excluding weekend hours

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, select, recursive-query

I have a table in postgres with 2 columns; ordered_timestamp, weekday_hours.

I want to create a third column 'due_timestamp' which is calculated using 'ordered_timestamp' plus 'weekday_hours' ...BUT excluding the hours that fall across the weekend (12:00am Sat to 12:00am Mon)

```
ordered_timestamp    | weekday_hours  | due_timestamp
2020-06-04 16:00:00  |             12 | 2020-06-05 04:00:00
2020-06-05 16:00:00  |             48 | 2020-06-09 16:00:00
```

Without the caveat of excluding weekend hours, I could use `ordered_timestamp + interval '1 hour' * weekday_hours`

weekday_hours can vary from 1hr to hundreds of hours in some cases.

It seems this situation needs something additional to filter out the weekend hours.

Comment: "exclude weekend hours" does not make sense to someone not familiar with your actual problem.  Please provide more explanation.

Comment: I have updated to make the explanation for weekend hours clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your date intervals may span over variying periods, I would use a quite brute force approach by enumarating  all 1 hour intervals that fall between the timestamps with `generate_series()`, and then counting only those that belong to working days:

```
select t.ordered_timestamp, t.due_timestamp, x.weekday_hours
from mytable t
cross join lateral (
    select count(*) filter(where extract(dow from ts) between 1 and 5) - 1 weekday_hours 
    from generate_series(ordered_timestamp, due_timestamp, '1 hour'::interval) s(ts)
) x
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=196f3a7d126078e1986128e88040565d)**:

```
ordered_timestamp   | due_timestamp       | weekday_hours
:------------------ | :------------------ | ------------:
2020-06-04 16:00:00 | 2020-06-05 04:00:00 |            12
2020-06-05 16:00:00 | 2020-06-09 16:00:00 |            48
```

Comment: thanks! this is the answer i was after. i didn't know about cross join lateral

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
case when  (EXTRACT(DOW FROM  ordered_timestamp ) = 6  )
     then  ordered_timestamp + interval '1 hour' * (weekday_hours+48)
     when  (EXTRACT(DOW FROM  ordered_timestamp ) = 0  )
     then  ordered_timestamp + interval '1 hour' * (weekday_hours+24)
 else
     ordered_timestamp + interval '1 hour' * weekday_hours
 end
```

Comment: This would work if the weekday_hours were always 12, but that isn't the case. they can be hundreds of hours in some instances

Comment: then you will need to create a function, there is no simple way to do this in plain sql.